# Ways to make this Search and Replace code better?

Tags: perl

I have this code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %map;
open my $MAP, '<', 'full_links' or die $!;
while (<$MAP>) {
    my ($key, $value) = /comments\/(.*)\/(.*)\//;
    $map{$key} = "$key/$value";
}

open my $IN, '<', 'html_links' or die $!;
open my $out, '>', "results" or die;
while (<$IN>) {
    s/comments\/(.*)"/comments\/$map{$1}\/"/g;
    print $out $_;
}
close $out;
```

that changes lines in html_links file

from `<a href="https://reddit.com/r/subreddit/comments/CODE/">title</a>`

to `<a href="https://reddit.com/r/subreddit/comments/CODE/title_of_the_post/">title</a>`

by looking at full_link file, that's filled with lines like this:

`https://reddit.com/r/subreddit/comments/CODE/title_of_the_post/`

But I feel like it looks a bit odd. Specifically the `$map{$key} = "$key/$value";` part and it's further use in the replacement. I feels like doing just `$map{$key} = $value` should be sufficient, but I dont know how to utilize it to make the replacement that I need.

Comment: Treating HTML like regular text is prone to more difficulty than you originally bargain for. You might take an hour or so learning to use Mojo::DOM, which has DOM searching and replacing built in, and in so doing will unlock a new skill that could be useful.

Comment: Yes, learn a library for HTML as DavidO says (`Mojo::DOM`, `HTML::TreeBuilder`, etc) -- that's one actually good thing you can make out of this (easy) task.  But then, also ...

Comment: (1) Shouldn't `CODE` be the key and `title_of...` its value? So `$map{$key} = $value;`. But as those names aren't informative perhaps `$title{$code} = $text;` (or other, yet better, names) (2) instead of greedy (and backtracking) `.*` use `[^/]` (3) In `while` replace only the next `/.../` segment after `CODE` -- look up `\K`, to drop all matches up to that point (so you don't have to retype them). // Submit code to "code review"

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it. What is the problem/enhancement you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with [Mojo::DOM](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/DOM). Let it find all of the A tags then change what's in their HREF values:

```
#!perl
use v5.14;

use Mojo::DOM;
use Mojo::URL;

my $html = <<'HERE';
<html>
<body>

<a href="https://reddit.com/r/subreddit/comments/CODE/">Some title</a>
<a href="https://example.com/">Leave alone</a>
<a href="https://reddit.com/r/subreddit/comments/CODE/">Other title</a>

</body>
</html>
HERE

# Create the Document object model
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);

$dom
    # find all the A tags in the HTML with CSS selectors
    # The ^= matches just the HREFs that start with that text
    ->find( 'a[href^=https://reddit.com/]' )
    ->map( sub {
        # take the slug from the text between the A opener and closer.
        # replace whitespace (or whatever) with underscores
        my $slug = lc($_->text) =~ s/\s+/_/gr;

        # add the slug to the last part of the URL's path
        my $url = Mojo::URL->new( $_->attr('href') );
        push $url->path->parts->@*, $slug;

        # give the HREF its new value
        $_->attr('href', $url)
        })
    ;

# The DOM now has the modified HTML
say $dom
```